# CSAPP tiny shell lab: stuck at sigprocmask

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb, system-calls

I am trying the tiny shell lab in CSAPP. But my code stucks when I input an command line.

```bash
steven@Steven:/mnt/f/大学/CSAPP/cmu15213/shlab-handout$ ./tsh
tsh> 123
tsh> 123: command not found
123
123
123
^\Terminating after receipt of SIGQUIT signal
steven@Steven:/mnt/f/大学/CSAPP/cmu15213/shlab-handout$
```

Link to the lab:

- Webpage: https://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/labs.html
- Writeup: https://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/shlab.pdf

I modified Makefile by adding `-Og -g` and tried to debug with GDB and VSCode.

I found the program get stuck on the `sigprocmask`. As shown in the following picture, if I click "Step Over", it continues to run and never stops.
[image]

I copy the relevant piece of code and ran it separately, it works correctly.

- code for testing: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MWZybqZqkZ/
- `tsh.c`: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/g86JpxvJhv/
- entire folder: https://filetransfer.io/data-package/2BkyuuSI#link

I have tested this both in WSL and a virtual machine, and both exhibited the same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I click "Step Over", it continues to run and never stops.

I reproduced that. So let's see what's going on.

```
gdb -q ./tsh
(gdb) break tsh.c:191
(gdb) b tsh.c:191
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40156a: file tsh.c, line 191.

(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/tsh
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
tsh> aaa
[Detaching after fork from child process 182]

aaa: command not found
Breakpoint 1, eval (cmdline=0x7fffffffd930 "aaa\n") at tsh.c:191
191         sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &prev, NULL);
(gdb) n
```

At this point everything hangs, so we must be stuck on `sigprocmask`, right?

Actually, we are not.

```
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00007ffff7eb5c37 in __GI___wait4 (pid=-1, stat_loc=0x7fffffffcd5c, options=3, usage=0x0)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wait4.c:30
30        return SYSCALL_CANCEL (wait4, pid, stat_loc, options, usage);
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7eb5c37 in __GI___wait4 (pid=-1, stat_loc=0x7fffffffcd5c, options=3, usage=0x0)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wait4.c:30
#1  0x0000000000401a02 in sigchld_handler (sig=17) at tsh.c:383
#2  <signal handler called>
#3  __GI___pthread_sigmask (how=2, newmask=<optimized out>, oldmask=0x0) at pthread_sigmask.c:43
#4  0x00007ffff7e18d8d in __GI___sigprocmask (how=<optimized out>, set=<optimized out>, oset=<optimized out>)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sigprocmask.c:25
#5  0x0000000000401583 in eval (cmdline=0x7fffffffd930 "aaa\n") at tsh.c:191
#6  0x000000000040142d in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffde68) at tsh.c:149
```

Now we see what's *actually* going on. The `sigprocmask` unblocks `SIGCHLD`, which results in *immediate* delivery of that signal *just before* `sigprocmask` was about to return. That in turn invokes the `sigchld_handler`, which *repeatedly* calls `waitpid` in a never-ending loop.

Why doesn't the loop terminate? Because the code expects `waitpid` to return `0` when there are no children, but that is not correct: `waitpid` returns `-1` in that case.

The following fix makes `tsh` work as one might expect:

```
 diff -u tsh.c.orig tsh.c
--- tsh.c.orig  2024-01-20 21:42:47.915401415 -0800
+++ tsh.c       2024-01-20 21:43:20.145996657 -0800
@@ -383,7 +383,7 @@
         pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG | WUNTRACED);

         // 如果没有僵尸进程，则退出
-        if (pid == 0)
+        if (pid == 0 || pid == -1)
             return;

         // 如果子进程终止导致waitpid从阻塞中恢复
```

```
./tsh
tsh> aaa
aaa: command not found
tsh> bbb
bbb: command not found
tsh>
```

Here is the relevant text from Linux [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wait.3p.html):

> If `waitpid()` was invoked with `WNOHANG` set in options, it has at least one child process specified by `pid` for which status is not available, and status is not available for any process specified by pid, 0 is returned. Otherwise, -1 shall be returned